# R code optimization

Tags: r

The code below runs for long time. It takes the data of 400k rows and 5 variables as target variables.Can it be optimized to reduce the processing time?

```
maxn <- function(n) function(x) order(x, decreasing = TRUE)[n]


for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
  for (j in 1:(5-x$count[i]))  {
    if (x$count[i]<5) {
      x[,j+17][i]<-colnames(x[,2:6])[maxn(j)(x[i,12:16])]
    } #else {x[,j+17][i]<-0}
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't show some code and ask what can be done more efficiently; rather describe what's your goal. An example input and the relative desired output would be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(microbenchmark)
big <- 100
x.orig <- matrix(sample(1:10, big * 22, replace = TRUE), nrow = big, ncol= 22)
x.orig <- as.data.frame(x)
x.orig$count <- sample(1:5, big, replace = TRUE)
x.orig[,17:22] <- NA
colnames(x.orig)[2:6] <- letters[1:5]
```

This is what my sample data looks like:

```
head(x.orig)


V1  a b  c d e V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 count
1  4  2 4 10 2 8  3  7  3   7   2   3   4   4   5   1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA     1
2  6  4 2  5 7 6  1  6  6   8   1   6   6  10   4   6  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA     5
3  5  9 8  9 6 2  6  6 10   5  10   9   9   7   5   6  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA     5
4  3  1 1  4 4 1  8  7  1   3   9   4   6   9   5   5  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA     3
5  2 10 6 10 9 1  3  7  8   8   7   2   2  10   6   8  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA     3
6  8  2 4  3 3 2 10  6  7   3   2   2   3   5  10   7  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA     2
```

Let's test your code:

```
maxn <- function(n) function(x) order(x, decreasing = TRUE)[n]
microbenchmark({
  x <- x.orig
  for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
    for (j in 1:(5-x$count[i]))  {
      if (x$count[i]<5) {
        x[,j+17][i]<-colnames(x[,2:6])[maxn(j)(x[i,12:16])]
      } #else {x[,j+17][i]<-0}
    }
  }
}, times = 10)

# min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# 134.2846 142.5086 163.6631 144.2383 159.6705 326.5948    10
```

So what's happening here?

```
head(x[,12:23]) 
  V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17  V18  V19  V20  V21 V22 count
1   3   4   4   5   1  NA    d    b    c    a  NA     1
2   6   6  10   4   6  NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  NA     5
3   9   9   7   5   6  NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  NA     5
4   4   6   9   5   5  NA    c    b <NA> <NA>  NA     3
5   2   2  10   6   8  NA    c    e <NA> <NA>  NA     3
6   2   3   5  10   7  NA    d    e    c <NA>  NA     2
```

I get it, you're reporting the biggest 5 - count numbers from columns 12:16.

```
microbenchmark({
  x1 <- x.orig
  output <- apply(x1[,c('count', paste0('V', 12:16))], 1, function (y) {
    ct <- y[1]
    if (ct >= 5) return(rep(NA, 5))
    res <- order(y[2:6], decreasing = TRUE)
    res[(6 - ct):5] <- NA
    res
  })
  output <- t(output)
  output[] <- colnames(x)[2:6][output]
  x1[, 18:22] <- output
}, times = 10)

#     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# 3.244582 3.438222 3.695123 3.616348 4.015643 4.282772    10
```

About 100 x faster.

```
head(x1[,12:23])
  V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17  V18  V19  V20  V21  V22 count
1   3   4   4   5   1  NA    d    b    c    a <NA>     1
2   6   6  10   4   6  NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>     5
3   9   9   7   5   6  NA <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>     5
4   4   6   9   5   5  NA    c    b <NA> <NA> <NA>     3
5   2   2  10   6   8  NA    c    e <NA> <NA> <NA>     3
6   2   3   5  10   7  NA    d    e    c <NA> <NA>     2
```

Looks the same. I checked this for 10000 elements and it still runs in about 1/10 second.

What's the trick?

- Don't create functions that return functions. Just order the data once.
- Don't loop through count. Just order the rows and throw away elements you don't want.